# My code runs perfectly on my computer but not when executed on server? PYTHON

Tags: python, mongodb, github

I have a script that extracts title, publish date and link from MongoDB and sends it via email to selected receipients. However, when I run it from a server (using Digital Ocean) via Github, the code does run but results are wrong.

Example

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

client=MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxx:yoQnE9BsxD8YqpqL@xxxxxxxx-z0q0x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db=client.xxxxxx


total=[]
for doc in db.noticias.find().sort("Fecha",-1):
    if doc["Fecha"]>=datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(hours=5,minutes=-60):
        del doc["_id"]
        doc["Fecha"]=doc["Fecha"]+datetime.timedelta(hours=-5)
        
        total.append("\n".join(str(x) for x in doc.values()))

total="\n\n".join(total)

if not total:
    pass
else:
    

    s=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.zoho.com",587)
    msg=MIMEText(total)
    sender="xxxx@zohomail.com"
    recipients="xxxx@gmail.com"
    msg["Subject"]="Noticias"
    msg["From"]=sender
    msg["To"]=recipients
    s.starttls()
    s.login("xxxx@zohomail.com","xxxxxxxx")
    s.sendmail(sender,recipients,msg.as_string())
```

The idea is to send the email, if there are news in the last hour from the MONGODB collection. When I run the code in my computer, the script sends the news correctly. However, when the code is run while I’m connected to DigitalOcean via Github, the code sends does not respect the conditional.

Comment: What condition is not being respected?

Comment: Either if the list "total" is empty or not, the script sends the email when script is run on server

Comment: "Use docker" is the answer

Comment: It's not possible that when total is empty, the script sends an email, unless you have not actually properly indented your code that runs on the server, and the part that sends the email is not actually nested under the `else`. I would suggest your check the contents of total, and that you make sure you are indenting properly

Comment: I only gave your code a cursory glance due to formatting issues, but it could possibly be a problem with your local computer having a different timezone than your server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answers guys.
Im really new to python coding and it was my first time using a remote server like DigitalOcean. What happened is that i cloned my github repository on the remote server and thought that every new push i did into my repo from my local computer was going to be seen on the directory of the remote server. So, when i executed from the server there was no way it could work because by the time i cloned my code, the script was not finished. Its a newcomers mistake.
Anyways, thank you for your time. Took a day to realize this.